# Null Space ,Column space, relationship between Singular Value Decomposition(SVD)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, control-theory, svd

I have a matrix like $\mathbf{L} = \begin{bmatrix}2&0&4\\0.5&1&0\end{bmatrix}$ And I want to find out the **image space** and **null space** of it.

---

What I did is like , I reduced the rows to \begin{bmatrix}1&0&2\\0&1&-1\end{bmatrix}. From this I got to know that the null space can be seen in the free variable column. Thus null space is $$c\cdot\begin{bmatrix}-2\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}$$.

1. What can I say about the column space of the matrix.? I know that the column space is the linear combination of the columns of **L**
2. When I find the `[U,S,V] = svd(L)` using Matlab. The matrices I am getting is,
   $$U=\begin{bmatrix}-0.9986&0.0531
   \\-0.0531&-0.9986\end{bmatrix}$$
   $$S=\begin{bmatrix}4.4781&0&0
   \\0&1.0940&0\end{bmatrix}$$
   $$V=\begin{bmatrix}
   -0.4519&-0.3593   &-0.8165\\
      -0.0119  & -0.9128  &  0.4082\\
      -0.8920   & 0.1942 &   0.4082
   \end{bmatrix}$$

I know that the last column of th **V** matrix corresponds to the **null space** of the matrix.
$$x_n = \begin{bmatrix}
-0.8165\\
0.4082\\
0.4082
\end{bmatrix} \Longleftrightarrow \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{-2}{\sqrt{6}}\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}
\end{bmatrix}$$

---

How can I get to know what are the image space of the matrix , and what to be done to get the image space came out of svd, from the normal image space means the linear combination of columns of $L$

Comment: You might find [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2062649/81360) helpful.

Comment: See also [this (briefer) post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3344096/81360).